# how to use custom django templatetag with django template if statement?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've made a django template tag that counts one of my custom user many-to-many field length:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def unread_messages_count(context):
    user = context['request'].user
    return len(user.messages_unread.all())
```

and within the template itself, I want to show it to user only if it's larger than zero, so I tried:

```
{% ifnotequal unread_messages_count 0 %}
   some code...
{% endifnotequal %}
```

but obviously it didn't work. not even with a 'with' statement:

```
{% with unread_messages_count as unread_count %}
    {% ifnotequal unread_count 0 %}
        some code...
    {% endifnotequal %}
{% endwith %}
```

How can I check that the variable is larger than 0 and only if it is, present some code to the user (including the number in the variable itself).
thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use an assignment tag..

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def unread_messages_count(context):
    user = context['request'].user
    return len(user.messages_unread.all())

{% unread_messages_count as cnt %}
{% if cnt %}
   foo
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Deprecated since version 1.9: "simple_tag can now store results in a template variable and should be used instead."

Answer (score 2):

you can use a django custom filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

```
def unread_messages_count(user_id):
  # x = unread_count   ## you have the user_id
  return x
```

and in the template

```
{% if request.user.id|unread_messages_count > 0 %}
  some code...
{% endif %}
```