# Django template custom tag as boolean

Tags: django, django-templates

This seems such a simple thing but I can't seem to get it to work for one, and two I can't seem to be getting a straight forward answer online on wether it can or can't be done.

I just want a simple tag that will work like so

```
{% if my_tag %}
 render something
{% else %}
 render something else
{% endif %}
```

now I don't care about filters or any other ways you might be able to do the same thing, I want it to look exactly like that, and work like described, I have a simple tag made that actually does return True or False as needed, and it's called if I call the tag like this

{% my_tag %}

however it does't get called if I add an if in front of the tag, is a feature this simple and logical not implemented?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use custom django templatetag with django template if statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767516/how-to-use-custom-django-templatetag-with-django-template-if-statement)

Comment: it's not a possible duplicate it is more than likely a duplicate, the reason I asked again is because the answer didn't really answer the question on weather or not it's actually possible to do it, there was no real clarification if the answer given was just the author's way of tackling the problem, or a necessity from django's inability to do have such a simple workflow

Comment: Have you seen this? https://gist.github.com/xtranophilist/6637377

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the link to the potential duplicate states, you can use an `assignment tag` similar to the following that will return the current time:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def get_current_time(format_string):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string)
```

Within your template you can then do what you are desiring to do:

```
{% if get_current_time %}
 ...show time
{% else %}
 ...don't show time
{% endif %}
```